# Missing file when getting files on Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get files on Android from Google Drive but some files are missing. I'm using this code (which can be found here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list):

```
ArrayList<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
Files.List request = service.files().list();

do{
    try{
        FileList files = request.execute();

        result.addAll(files.getItems());
        request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
    request.setPageToken(null);
    }
}
while(request.getPageToken() != null
        && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
```

With this code, I get 4 files. However, I have more than 4 files on Google Drive and this 4 files match those that I sent from my application. When I test the "Try it!" section (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#try-it), it works fine and all the files are found.

Do you have any ideas on what could be a problem?

Comment: What's the scope you are using with the listing in the app?

Comment: My final goal is to get all shared files with the user, but I already can't get all user files.

Comment: What I'm asking is whether you're authorized for a more restricted scope like `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`?

Comment: Thank you so much! You're absolutely right, I had a too restrictive scope.